# XSLT Grouping with SUM issue when first subnode not exists

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="State.xsl" ?>

<StateData>
<States>    
    <State>
        <StateName>State1</StateName>
        <Districts>
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AT</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>A</DistrictName>              
                <Population>10000</Population>              
            </District>         
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AT</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>B</DistrictName>      
                <Population>5000</Population>                   
            </District>     
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AT</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>A</DistrictName>
                <Population>2000</Population>               
            </District>                 
        </Districts>
    </State>
    <State>
        <StateName>State2</StateName>
        <Districts>
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AC</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>C</DistrictName>
                <Population>8000</Population>               
            </District>         
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AT</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>B</DistrictName>      
                <Population>5500</Population>                   
            </District>     
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AP</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>A</DistrictName>
                <Population>1000</Population>               
            </District> 
        </Districts>
    </State>
</States>
</StateData>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">  
   <xsl:key name="district-by-state" match="District" use="concat(TranslatedDistrictName,
                       DistrictName[not(string(../TranslatedDistrictName))])" /> 
    <xsl:template match="StateData">
        <xsl:for-each select="States/State">                

                <xsl:for-each select="Districts/District[count(. | key('district-by-state', concat(TranslatedDistrictName,
                       DistrictName[not(string(../TranslatedDistrictName))]))[1]) = 1]">    
                    <hr/>                   
                    - <xsl:value-of select="concat(TranslatedDistrictName,
                       DistrictName[not(string(../TranslatedDistrictName))])"/> 
                     --<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('district-by-state', concat(TranslatedDistrictName,
                        DistrictName[not(string(../TranslatedDistrictName))]))/Population)" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            <hr/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

- AT --22500
- AC --8000
- AP --1000

**As of now, This is working perfect But the moment I add a new state having no district SUM is not working properly.**

Note - Added a new State having no Districts tag instead used **"District1"**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="State.xsl" ?>

<StateData>
<States>
    <State>
        <StateName>State3</StateName>
        <Districts1>
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AT</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>A</DistrictName>              
                <Population>10000</Population>              
            </District>         
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AT</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>B</DistrictName>      
                <Population>5000</Population>                   
            </District>     
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AT</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>A</DistrictName>
                <Population>2000</Population>               
            </District>                 
        </Districts1>
    </State>
    <State>
        <StateName>State1</StateName>
        <Districts>
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AT</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>A</DistrictName>              
                <Population>10000</Population>              
            </District>         
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AT</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>B</DistrictName>      
                <Population>5000</Population>                   
            </District>     
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AT</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>A</DistrictName>
                <Population>2000</Population>               
            </District>                 
        </Districts>
    </State>
    <State>
        <StateName>State2</StateName>
        <Districts>
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AC</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>C</DistrictName>
                <Population>8000</Population>               
            </District>         
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AT</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>B</DistrictName>      
                <Population>5500</Population>                   
            </District>     
            <District>
                <TranslatedDistrictName>AP</TranslatedDistrictName>
                <DistrictName>A</DistrictName>
                <Population>1000</Population>               
            </District> 
        </Districts>
    </State>
</States>
</StateData>
```

**Result**

- AC --8000
- AP --1000

**Here, SUM for District AT is missing .**

**Expected Result**

AT --22500
AC --8000
AP --1000

Comment: *Not exists* and *exists under a different name* are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pick up `District` elements under `Districts1` elements, then one solution is to amend the key to only match `District` elements under `Districts` elements

```
  <xsl:key name="district-by-state" match="Districts/District" use="concat(TranslatedDistrictName,
                   DistrictName[not(string(../TranslatedDistrictName))])" />
```

You might also want to change your `xsl:for-each` to only select `State` elements with child `Districts` nodes

```
<xsl:for-each select="States/State[Districts]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">  
   <xsl:key name="district-by-state" match="Districts/District" use="concat(TranslatedDistrictName,
                       DistrictName[not(string(../TranslatedDistrictName))])" /> 

    <xsl:template match="StateData">
        <xsl:for-each select="States/State[Districts]">                

                <xsl:for-each select="Districts/District[count(. | key('district-by-state', concat(TranslatedDistrictName,
                       DistrictName[not(string(../TranslatedDistrictName))]))[1]) = 1]">    
                    <hr/>                   
                    - <xsl:value-of select="concat(TranslatedDistrictName,
                       DistrictName[not(string(../TranslatedDistrictName))])"/> 
                     --<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('district-by-state', concat(TranslatedDistrictName,
                        DistrictName[not(string(../TranslatedDistrictName))]))/Population)" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            <hr/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I do not want to pick Districts1 but would like to see the result of AT(inside the State1) that is the part of Districts tag. I pointed the problem that the moment we add Districts1 in the xml Its ignore all other Districts tag inside that State.

Comment: My apologies @Manish, I misunderstood the question. However, I have now re-written my answer with a different solution.

Comment: Little more explanation.. It seems I am not able to better explain the scenario..

Comment: Little more explanation.. It seems I am not able to better explain the scenario..   As you see there were 2 states(State1 and State2) in first xml and it was working fine.. The moment I have added one more state(State3) without any districts (as the first state in xml) the group sum behaviour getting worse.. As we loop through Xpath Districts/District it ignore AT that is available in State1 and State2.

Comment: It might help if you showed the expected output in this new case. Thanks

Comment: Expected output is same (As I have added a new state without any districts and didn't change in existing states.) - AT --22500
AC --8000
AP --1000

Comment: My answer should produce that output. See http://xsltransform.net/94AbWBj

Comment: Thanks Tim.. Its working for above xml.. But I am still not able to get the correct result in my actual scenario [xsltransform.net/bFWR5Em](http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5Em/1)..  Expected Result - Stacey-- 20                       Result is proper until we add tag <DeductionAdjustmentsNotToInclude>.

Comment: Result is fine until we replace a node <DeductionAdjustments> with <DeductionAdjustmentsNotToInclude>.

Comment: Your actual XML is quite different to what is shown in the question, which has lead to the confusion. It would have helped if the XML in your question was more representative of what you were trying to do. For you actual XML, take a look at http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5Em/2 which might do what you want. If you still can't get it to work, I suggest you ask a whole new question. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Tim.. Your solution is working perfect for my scenario.